# Why I've got type mismatch exception?

Tags: scala

I got a weird exception in this snippet

```
 val splitted = "This is a text that to test something".split("\\,|\\ ")
 val map = mutable.Map[Int, List[String]]()
 (0 to splitted.length).foreach {
     case i =>map(i) = map.getOrElse(i,List[String]("")) ++ splitted(i)
 }
```

but I have got this exception:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : List[Any]
 required: List[String]
      case i =>map(i) = map.getOrElse(i,List("")) ++ splitted(i)
                                              ^                                                  ^
```

Comment: are you sure this code is correct ? what are you trying to do ? , map(i) is expecting a int , List

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are yet another victim of the inference of `Any`.

```
scala> map.getOrElse(7,List[String](""))
res3: List[String] = List("")

scala> res3 ++ "abc"
res4: List[Any] = List("", a, b, c)
```

Here's the same thing with `-Xlint`:

```
scala> (0 to splitted.length).foreach {
     case i =>map(i) = map.getOrElse(i,List[String]("")) ++ splitted(i)
 }
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Any]
 required: List[String]
                   case i =>map(i) = map.getOrElse(i,List[String]("")) ++ splitted(i)
                                                                       ^

scala> val res3 = { map.getOrElse(7,List[String]("")) }
<console>:6: warning: Unused import
import collection.mutable
                  ^
res3: List[String] = List("")

scala> res3 ++ "abc"
<console>:11: warning: a type was inferred to be `Any`; this may indicate a programming error.
              res3 ++ "abc"
                      ^
res1: List[Any] = List("", a, b, c)
```

Unfortunately, the `-Xlint` warning is smothered by the error.

And, under `-Xlint -Xfatal-warnings`, the warning doesn't get a chance to error out:

```
scala> (0 to splitted.length).foreach {
     case i =>map(i) = map.getOrElse(i,List[String]("")) ++ splitted(i)
 }
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Any]
 required: List[String]
                   case i =>map(i) = map.getOrElse(i,List[String]("")) ++ splitted(i)
                                                                       ^
```

If the warning is not inside the closure, then you get the helpful message under `-Xlint -Xfatal-warnings`:

```
val ss: List[String] = (null: mutable.Map[Int,List[String]]).getOrElse(0,List.empty[String]) ++ "abc"
```

Answer (score 2):

`splitted(i)` is a `String` and `++` (which expects a collection) treats String like `Array[Char]`, which then results in the common supertype `List[Any]`.

Example:

```
val list = List("a", "b") ++ "hello"
println(list) //prints List(a, b, h, e, l, l, o) and is of type List[Any]
```

If it doesn't matter where it's inserted then i would do it like this:

```
case i => map(i) = splitted(i) :: map.getOrElse(i,List[String](""))
```

If it should be appended:

```
case i => map(i) = map.getOrElse(i,List[String]("")) :+ splitted(i)
```

Comment: A String is a collection. `Seq('a','b') ++ "cde"`

Comment: Also just thought about that, modified it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to do with that code but here's a working version:

```
(0 to splitted.length-1).foreach {
  case i =>map(i) = (map.getOrElse(i,List[String]("")) :+ splitted(i))
}
```

which will create:

```
println(map)
Map(2 -> List(, a), 5 -> List(, to), 4 -> List(, that), 7 -> List(, something), 1 -> List(, is), 3 -> List(, text), 6 -> List(, test), 0 -> List(, This))
```

**EDIT**: Maybe what you need is the following:

```
splitted.zipWithIndex.map{case (s,i)=>(i,s)}.toMap
```

which results in:

```
Map(0 -> This, 5 -> to, 1 -> is, 6 -> test, 2 -> a, 7 -> something, 3 -> text, 4 -> that)
```

or more efficiently:

```
((0 to splitted.length-1) zip splitted).toMap
```

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
 val splitted = "This is a text that to test something".split("\\,|\\ ")
 val map = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, List[String]]()
 (0 until splitted.length).foreach {
     case i =>map(i) = map.getOrElse(i,List[String]("")) :+ splitted(i)
 }
```

Which outputs:

```
scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,List[String]] = Map(2 -> List("", a), 5 -> List("", to), 4 -> List("", that), 7 -> List("", something), 1 -> List("", is), 3 -> List("", text), 6 -> List("", test), 0 -> List("", This))
```

Also, note the difference between `to` and `until`. Using `to` in  will give and `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`.

```
scala> val l = List(1,2,3)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
scala> 0 to l.length
res51: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range(0, 1, 2, 3)
scala> 0 until l.length
res52: scala.collection.immutable.Range = Range(0, 1, 2)
```